# How can I find out all of the checked out files in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We are using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and TFS 2010 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008, R2. For an upcoming code freeze, I need to quickly check whether any developers have files checked out. Is there a way to do this which is built into TFS and/or Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Do you get the lock icons in the Solution Explorer?  Sight down the list, and see if you see any with red checkmarks next to them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Although this is useful, I need to recursively read all files in a large number of sub projects. I don't want to have to drill down into every folder.

Comment: It's a pity that there isn't a simple TFS GUI function for this, which VSS had!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As an alternative to using the `tf status` command you can also install the [TFS 2010 power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f).

You can then right click on any folder in Source Control Explorer and select "Find in source control" > "Status"

the default option is to find all checked out files in the path you have slected.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to export the results to excel?

Comment: Here is the VS2015 version too!   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power

Answer (score 27):

For a built-in method, you can use the [tf command line tool's status command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s5ae285(v=vs.100).aspx).

Just open a Visual Studio command prompt from your start menu to use it. By default it lists the status of your own workspace but if you can figure out the command line you can list other people's workspaces too.

**Edit:**

`tf status /user:* /recursive` should do what you want.
If you run it in a locally-mapped folder you won't need to specify which files to search, or you can just include a filespec like `tf status $/MyProject/SomeFolder/*.* /user:* /recursive`

Comment: MSDN has http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s5ae285(v=vs.100).aspx. With the itemspec as the folder I was able to view the same results as right-clicking on the folder as stated in James Reed's answer by: `tf status myFolder\* /user:* /recursive` +1 btw

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the /recursive bit. Have updated my answer to be more correct.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old, but none of the answers gave specific examples of how to make this work.  So here is what I came up with (TFS Server 2008).

First, open the Visual Studio Developer command prompt.

Execute the following command:

```
tf status $/MyFolder /user:* /recursive
```

The form being:

> **tf status** *itemspec* **/user:***username* **/recursive**

The key is the **/user:*** parameter, which forces TFS to look at the server and determine all the checked out files in the path specified in the *itemspec* parameter.  If you don't use the wildcard you will only see files you personally have checked out.

For the specific use case, you would want to put this in a file versus to screen so it would look like this:

```
tf status $/MyFolder /user:* /recursive > c:\MyPendingCheckouts.txt
```

Note I ran this with VS2012 command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

1. Right click on the top most folder that you want to start in
2. Choose "Find In Source Control"
3. Choose "Status"
4. Check "Recursive"
5. Check "Status"
6. Enter userid in the "Display files checked out to:" box (i have to include my domain, i.e. domain\userid)
7. Click "Find"

Comment: This isn't in TFS 2010 or VS 2010. Are you using a plug-in?

Comment: I am able to perform the suggested steps  in (even in) VS 2008. Note that I have installed power tools.

Comment: Number 6 was the key (adding in the domain) that allowed me to do a specific user search.

Answer (score 1):

I find [TFS Side Kicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) useful for this. You can use the status side kick to look for checkouts.

Comment: I found TFS Side Kicks incompatible with my version of Windows. I installed version 2.4 on Windows Server 2008, R2 (x64). It couldn't read the registry.